# mysql error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

I try to write a code to find the nearest value But my code  have some syntex error please help
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

```
  update member t1
    set Latid = (
        select id 
        from markersphuket t2
        where t2.MU = t1.Moo
        order by abs(t2.hno2 - t1.Hno2)
        limit 1
```

Comment: Do you want to close this parenthesis? `set Latid = (`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRy:

```
update member t1
    set Latid = (
        select id 
        from markersphuket t2
        where t2.MU = t1.Moo
        order by abs(t2.hno2 - t1.Hno2)
        limit 1 )
WHERE 1 // will update all the rows of member table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
update member t1
set Latid = (
    select id 
    from markersphuket t2
    where t2.MU = t1.Moo
    order by abs(t2.hno2 - t1.Hno2)
)
    limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss the last `)`?

```
  update member t1
    set Latid = (
        select id 
        from markersphuket t2
        where t2.MU = t1.Moo
        order by abs(t2.hno2 - t1.Hno2)
        limit 1
    )
```